# create oracle job run procedure with parameters once

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I want to create oracle job in specific date and time that runs only on that date and time once
and then dropped automatically.

The job should runs a procedure with 2 parameters also .

note: l_id I used this variable to add number beside procedure name to avoid any kind of duplication.

P94_DATE: the user will choose date and time and it will be stored in that variable.

here what I found so far but when I run this , it gives me 'statement proceed' but when I check if the job created successfully or not on 'sys.all_scheduler_jobs'
it doesn't exist.

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name           =>  'eba_sb_reminder_s'||l_id,
job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
 job_action         =>  'BEGIN send_Schedule_reminders(1,2); END;',
 start_date         =>  :P94_DATE, -- I need to assign time also !!
 enabled            =>  true,
comments           => 'check if there is new reminders needs to be send in specific date and time'


 );
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `job_type` is set to `STORE_PROCEDURE` you must specify the name of the procedure in `job_action`.

The parameter `start_date` is of type `DATE`, which has a time as well in Oracle. You just need to set `:p94_date` with a correct value, containing a date and a time part.

If the procedure has parameters, you need to use `DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value` to specify a parameter-value.

Edit: Sample modified

Sample:

```
BEGIN
   -- This needs to be configured just once.
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program(program_name          => 'test_program',
                                 program_type          => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                 program_action        => 'test',
                                 number_of_arguments   => 2,
                                 enabled               => FALSE,
                                 comments              => 'Comment');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.define_program_argument(program_name        => 'test_program',
                                          argument_name       => 'p1',
                                          argument_position   => 1,
                                          argument_type       => 'NUMBER',
                                          DEFAULT_VALUE       => NULL);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.define_program_argument(program_name        => 'test_program',
                                          argument_name       => 'p2',
                                          argument_position   => 2,
                                          argument_type       => 'NUMBER',
                                          DEFAULT_VALUE       => NULL);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(name => 'test_program');

   -- Create job
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
      job_name       => 'test_job',
      program_name   => 'test_program',
      start_date     => :p94_date,
      enabled        => FALSE,
      comments       => 'check if there is new reminders needs to be send in specific date and time');

   -- Set Procedure Parameter
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value(job_name => 'test_job', argument_position => 1, argument_value => 1);
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value(job_name => 'test_job', argument_position => 2, argument_value => 2);

   -- Enable job
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(name => 'test_job');
END;
```

Comment: it shows error :ORA-27465: invalid value 1 for attribute ARGUMENT_POSITION

Comment: It works after adding number of arguments attribute

Answer (score 0):

"It's not working" is not found an any error message reference, and is totally devoid of actionable information.
That said:

1. You specify JOB_TYPE as  STORED_PROCEDURE, so JOB_ACTION should be the name of a stored procedure. Instead you give it the code for an anonymous block.
2. JOB_NAME include a string concatenation that seems to try to include a variable.  Where does that value come from and how do you think it is being populated when you execute this CREATE_JOB?

3)START_DATE also seems to try to include a variable/parameter.  Again, Where does that value come from and how do you think it is being populated when you execute this CREATE_JOB?

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
job_name           =>  'eba_sb_reminder_s',
job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
 job_action         =>  'send_Schedule_reminders(1,2)',
 start_date         =>  to_date('2021-03-22 13:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
 enabled            =>  true,
comments           => 'check if there is new reminders needs to be send in specific date and time'
```

If this fails to meet your requirement (esp those attempts to include some sort of paramter, please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve with them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I tried your code but this error show up ( ORA-27452: "send_Schedule_reminders(1,2)" is an invalid name for a database object. )

Comment: I took that from your pl/sql block.  So what is the name (and owner) of the procedure you want to execute?   SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE UPPER(OBJECT_NAME)='SEND_SCHEDULE_REMINDERS';  Or use your original job_action and change job_type to 'PLSQL_BLOCK'. You should review the docs on dbms_scheduler.create_job, at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-7E744D62-13F6-40E9-91F0-1569E6C38BBC, paying particular attention to job_type and job_action.